# JAVA: How to set a string value to be returned, when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing

When I call the Main.main(null) from other .java file,
`return_str = "Not assigned!";` is returned by the main(), before the user could press the "Student" button and
`return_str = "student sign-in";` is executed.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static JPanel contentPane;
    static Main frame;
    static String return_str;
    static JButton btnStudent = new JButton("Student");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static String main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    btnStudent.addActionListener(new Action_student());
                    contentPane.add(btnStudent);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return_str = "Not assigned!";
        System.out.println(return_str);
        return return_str;
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Main() {
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        btnStudent.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnStudent.setBounds(171, 148, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnStudent);
        
    }
    
    static class Action_student implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            return_str = "student sign-in";
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase, so it should be ActionStudent, or even better: you would just use a lambda to do that, instead of creating an inner class like you did.

Answer (score 1):

As the method already indicates, the frame creation is 'invoked later' meaning in another thread.
So you have to let your main routine wait for the button to be pressed.

Add a new variable to the Main class:

```
static boolean studentEntered = false;
```

In the action listener sets the studentEntered flag to true:

```
static class Action_student implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        return_str = "student sign-in";
        Main.studentEntered = true;
    }
}
```

In the main method you change your last lines to:

```
return_str = "Not assigned!";
while (!studentEntered) {
    // loop as long as the flag is not switched
}
System.out.println(return_str);
try {
    return return_str;
} finally {
    // close the frame by the application otherwise your application will not stop
    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped. But the only issue now is when I am returning the return_str value, it is not getting assigned to str_send. I am calling it like this...str_send = Main.main(null);

Comment: Does the `System.out.println(return_str);`prints the correct value ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how a Listener works!

When you create your button, you are assigning a listener to that, it means that **ONLY** when the button is pressed your string is going to change!

The output is correct, because after creating the listener it executes the rest of code, in your case

```
return_str = "Not assigned!";
System.out.println(return_str);
```

You have to change the way you return the string.